# Font awesome icons become squares when uploaded to server, only if I remove all.js from project folder

Tags: javascript, css, font-awesome

Font awesome is being loaded from locally stored files.

Font awesome loads icons fine on a local server (with all.js file removed), but do not load when deployed to a server. When deployed to server, the animations still occur, but the icons are missing. I'm honestly not entirely sure what the js file is doing, and why it does not make a difference on my local machine if the file is there or not.

I include the css file in the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css" />
```

javascript I am commenting out:

```
<script src="node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are those assets under node_modules actually being pushed your web server?

In some environments, node_modules is ignored (like .gitignore). So can you confirm that the all.css is actually where you expect it to be on the web server? I would also inspect the Network activity when loading the page, such as in the network tab in Google Chrome DevTools, to see whether that all.css is being loaded correctly. Most likely, it's not.

As for all.js vs. all.css: these are two different technologies. Font Awesome 5 is available as *either* "Webfonts with CSS" (all.css) or "SVG with JavaScript" (all.js). So you should choose one of those--up to your needs or preferences--but not both.

Comment: Looks like this solved it! My deployed environment didn't include the webfonts folder, and the path to it was incorrect in the all.css file as well. Thanks!